# Initializing node.js environment through C++ application

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js

Just want to know is it possible to initialize/start node.js from C++ application. Root of this question is that I am having a C++ console application, which launches an javascript application which does **require('os')**.Now It is failing as I suppose node.js is missing or not initialized as I am getting Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Edit 1:
I tried browserify and it resolved the require() issue. Now problem is that I am not able to use any of the methods exposed by the required module.
I am getting `"undefined is not a function"` error.

Comment: How are you launching your javascript application?

Comment: Its an extension precisely an Adobe CEP extension.

Answer (score 0):

Since `require` is not defined it seems like your JavaScript engine is not supporting the [CommonJS](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1) specification. You cannot run node modules without CommonJS support.

Generally it's hard to run node modules anywhere but in node, because of the node internals. There exists software to transform node modules and scripts to other platforms like [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) and [browserify](http://browserify.org/). Maybe those will create JavaScript that you can use in your project.

Comment: Thanks bolav for pointing out the issues and suggesting some of the third party platforms. I tried using browserify and It actually resolved my require() issue. But the catch is I am not able to use any of the methods that belongs to the required module. It would be great if you could hint some workarounds.